# Java calling method based on type

Tags: java, filter

I'm making a Java class where I can apply a filter (searchterms) on a List with DTO's. The filter looks like:

```
[{ field: "price", value: "10.0" }, { field: "name", value: "%phone%" }]
```

In my class I have the following method, to apply all the filters to the list:

```
    public List<T> applyFilters(List<T> input, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> searchTerms) {
    for (LinkedHashMap<String, String> searchTerm : searchTerms) {
        input = input.stream()
                .filter(row -> {
                    try {
                        return applySingleFilter(row, searchTerm);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new CustomGraphQLException(400, "The filter field is not a valid field in this type");
                    }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    return input;
}
```

But the `applySingleFilter` has different implementations based on the type of a field. Like for Strings I create a Regex:

```
    private boolean applySingleStringFilter (T category, LinkedHashMap<String, String> searchTerm) throws Exception {
    String patternString = createCompareRegex(searchTerm.get("value"));

    String propertyValue = (String) PropertyUtils.getProperty(category, searchTerm.get("field"));
    return propertyValue.matches(patternString);
}
```

But for like a Float I want another comparison, I don't want to apply the Regex to a float. What is the best way to make sure the correct method is called based on the type of the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'd first need to know the type of the field and once you have that information you could maintain a repository of filters that apply to the type (some casting might be required though).

We had a similar system in place which in essence looked like this:

```
interface Filter<T> {
  Class<T> getHandledType();
  boolean apply(T element);
}

class DoubleFilter implements Filter<Double> {
   public Class<Double> getHandledType() { return Double.class; }
   boolean apply(Double element) {
     //filter here
   }
}
```

The repository was basically a `Map<Class<?>, Filter<?>>` and using it was like:

```
 Object fieldValue = //get the field value;
 Class<?> fieldType = fieldValue.getClass(); //ofc, check for null first
 Filter<?> filter = repo.get(fieldType);
 if( filter != null ) {
   //nasty cast to a raw type to tell the compiler to allow the call
   ((Filter)filter).apply(fieldValue);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!! This was exactly what I was looking for!